# Using typeof to typeof doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I get how typeof can be an operator or a function. But when I do

```js
console.log(typeof(typeof));
```

I got this message
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

So what am i doing wrong here? What can i do to get the data type of typeof?

Comment: `typeof` is **only** an operator.

Comment: `typeof(+)` (or `typeof +`, since it is indeed an operator and therefore doesn't need parentheses) fails with the same error, which hopefully isn't a surprise. Despite it being all alphanumeric characters, `typeof` is an operator just like `+` and friends, so it behaves the same way.

Comment: I think this is a fine question. It bothers me that someone would downvote this and vote to close.

Comment: This is a common mistake made by beginners. Just because one can wrap parenthesis around an operand it does not turn the preceding operator into a function.

Comment: Removing all the content is considered vandalism. Please don't do this. Questions and answers at StackOverflow are not a free service for you  exclusively but shall also help other visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` is an operator. (Source: [**MDN Web Docs: typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).)

To sum up the documentation on operators, I'll say this: Every operator must work on an operand (or non-operator).  A unary operator requires only one operand (`i++`, `!j`), a binary operator requires two operands (`1+2`, `'a' + 'b'`), and there's even a special ternary operator.  (Source: [**MDN Web Docs: Expressions and operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).)  Or, if you like the original text...

> A binary operator requires two operands, one before the operator and one after the operator...
>
> A unary operator requires a single operand...

So, it's not possible to do...

- `+ +`
- `+ ==`
- `typeof +`

Etc..  Naturally, then, `typeof typeof` will naturally not work, as it violates the rule about unary operators requiring operands.